# Deleting empty column from 3D matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix `A` of size `3 x 100 x 19`.

```
 A(3x100x1) = 
Columns 1 through 4

0.0080    0.0090    0.0100    0.0110
0.1350    0.1350    0.1350    0.1350
1.7564    1.7564    1.7564    1.7582

Columns 5 through 8

0.0120    0.0130        0.0140     0
0.1350    0.1350        0.1350     0
1.7599    1.7599        1.7655     0 .... columns 100


 A(3x100x2) = 

 Columns 5 through 8

     0         0         0    0.0150
     0         0         0    0.1350
     0         0         0    1.7599... and so on till 100 column
```

Similarly till `A(3x100x19)`

I want to delete empty columns of 3D matrices and need `A(3x10x1)`, `A(3x10x2)` an so on without empty columns.

I tried

```
    A(:,all(A == 0),:) = [] % it did not work.
```

I also tried

```
for m = 1:19
    B = A(:,:,segId)
    B(:,all(A == 0),:) = [];
end                               %% It did not work.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you have lots of empty  entries, you could have a look at sparse matrices: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Imagine this as a cube: you can't go about punching holes in it in MATLAB. You need a solid cube. Say I eliminate `A(2,4,5)`, how is MATLAB supposed to show that? Swiss cheese is no option for MATLAB, so I'd leave the columns at zero, or, alternatively, set them to `nan`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So , that means deleting empty rows or columns from the 3d matrix is not possible.

Comment: Indeed. You need to have your matrix to be a rectangle in 2D, a girder in 3D and their equivalents in higher dimensions. Since I have no idea why you want this, I can only suggest to either make your program ignore `0` values, or put in some fill value like `-9999` or `nan`.

Comment: Okay. How can I convert this matrix into sparse matrix? Because I don't think, sparse 3d matrix is possible.? @Adriaan

Comment: @Akash oh indeed. I forgot you can't actually do that. Probably because you need to store `N+1` numbers for an `N` dimensional matrix (i.e. its index in all dimensions + the actual value of the element). So it's limited to 2 dimensions max. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: No problem. I have tried to use cell array. It work, but slow. If you can help with that? @ Adriaan.<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749648/using-loop-instead-of-arrayfun-in-matlab>

Comment: @Akash a sparse matrix isn't going to help you here, your matrix is not sparse.