# Using loop instead of arrayfun in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have created 3d Cell array "mycell" of size 1x100x19.

```
val(:,:,1) = 

Columns 1 through 3

{3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}

Columns 4 through 6

{3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}

Columns 7 through 13

[]    []    []    []    []    []    [].....


val(:,:,2) = 

Columns 1 through 7

[]    []    []    []    []    []    []

Columns 8 through 13

{3x1 cell}    []    []    []    []    []......
```

and so on till mycell(:,:,19).

As I cannot delete empty rows or colums, I concatenate using arrayfun like this:

```
mycell = arrayfun(@(x)cat(2, mycell{:,:,x}), 1:size(mycell, 3), 'uni', 0);
```

It gives me result like this:

```
Columns 1 through 3

{3x6 cell}    {3x1 cell}    {3x73 cell} ....
```

The result is okay but it is slow.Is there any way that I can do this with loop instead of arrayfun, because I check for loop is faster than arrayfun.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @rayryeng, `cellfun()` as instead is slower than the loop (strange but true). Same story might apply to `arrayfun()` as well? I'm not an expert on `arrayfun()`, to be honest, that's why I'm asking

Comment: This way of cells will be slower than using your previous 3D matrix. Why are you so keen on deleting the zeros in the first place? You still haven't told us that...

Comment: @Alessiox Yeah, `cellfun()` is *painfully* slow. I don't think `arrayfun()` is nearly that bad.

Comment: @Akash It would be helpful if you told us what you're actually trying to achieve here. I keep getting the feeling that you're making something simple much more complicated than it needs to be.